# Troubleshooting a pHAT DAC on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian, i2c, pi-zero-w, phat-dac

I'm trying to get the [pHAT DAC](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/phat_dac) to work with my Raspberry Pi Zero W on running Raspbian Jessie Lite 4.4, but I cannot get it to output any sound.

I followed [Pimoroni's own tutorial](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/phat/raspberry-pi-phat-dac-install) and tried both the "Automated setup":

```
curl https://get.pimoroni.com/phatdac | bash
```

and the "Manual set up" so far, without luck.

Running `aplay -l`, after installing and rebooting, outputs this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But neither their test sounds, nor trying to play some local .wav files outputs any sound.

Do you have any advice on how to make it work?
Might I have screwed up the soldering?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Pi Zero Wireless running Raspbian Jessie Lite (4.4.50+) with a pHAT DAC.
I ran the automated install -

`curl https://get.pimoroni.com/phatdac | bash`

At the end of running this script it asked me if I wanted to test it, (yes), and it successfully played the sounds through the headphones I had attached.

Running `aplay -l` gives me the same output as you:

```
pi@blackpi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`
```

So... sounds like it might be your soldering ?...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. Isn't it weird though that `aplay -l` gives me any result at all? Or is that merely software configs, and doesn't have to do what is actually attached or not?

Comment: Software / Config. When I remove the pHAT DAC, reboot and run `aplay -l` again, I get the same output...